# When to use "one of"?

Tags: possessives

[image]

Although the question is about possessives, I got it wrong because I am confused whether to use *one of* or not.

The correct answer is D. I marked C because I thought that D is awkward and wordy.

Please help me with this concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(C) is wrong because you cannot say:

- *Mike Tyson (singular) was boxing's most fearsome competitor**s** (plural).

You need the partitive "one of" to make the subject complement singular.

If Tyson was considered **the** most fearsome boxer of all, then you could say:

- Mike Tyson was boxing's most fearsome **competitor**.